# How can I initialize a git submodule without checking out a commit?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a Git project containing submodules. For some of those submodules the repos are *massive*, taking minutes upon minutes to clone, and I need only a very small percentage of the source files in them. Cloning the top-level repo does not automatically clone the submodules, as is correct. I can call `git submodules init <subdirectory>` to get the submodules initialized, including which commit hash the submodule should be pointing to in its repo.

The next step would typically be to call `git submodule update --init --recursive` to initialize the file tree in each of the submodule directories. However, I only want a small portion of the files in these submodules. If I do an initial update and wait the interminable amount of time required to clone the whole thing, I can do the following to use a sparse checkout to limit the files on the system:

```
cd <submodule directory>
git sparse-checkout set foo/bar/baz
cd <back to top-level project root>
```

That will remove the unneeded files from the submodule, but that's suboptimal, since the submodule had to be cloned with the full set of files anyway. If this weren't in a submodule, I'd do this using a modern Git client:

```
git clone --sparse <repo url> <directory>
cd <directory>
git sparse-checkout add foo/bar/baz
git pull
git checkout <required branch>
```

Is there a way to get the `git submodule update` to only do the clone bit with no full checkout so I can set the sparse checkout I need before doing the *actual* update to retrieve the files (and *only* the files) I want?

Comment: You can configure submodules for both shallow clone and sparse checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+shallow+sparse

Comment: @phd I can see the "shallow" case pretty clearly, but the "sparse checkout" option seems to be eluding me. Even using `git config submodule.<name>.update <command>`, it still seems to be cloning the entire repo into the target directory. What would you use for `<command>` to (1) set up the sparse checkout, and (2) make sure that's all that is pulled into the submodule directory?

Comment: It should be *something like* `git sparse-checkout init && git sparse-checkout set dir1 dir2 file3 && git checkout`. Also see https://www.reedbeta.com/made/git-partial-submodule/

Comment: I would've thought that type of script would work too, but it doesn't. The sparse checkout is not applied when `git submodule update` is executed.

Comment: `git config submodule.<name>.update !<command>` Used an exclamation sign?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's how it's documented; that's how I attempted to use it.